# How to make a Bootstrap 3 Alert flyin from top of screen to center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been searching high and low for some examples of a Bootstrap 3 Alert box flying in from to top of screen and ending at center screen on top of all elements.

I'm finding lots re. modals, but how do i accomplish this behavior for a alert box?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407544/animate-moving-div-from-bottom-to-top-on-hover) by chipChocolate.py, and the fiddle he provided [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/nag9kfLx/). 
It is not exactly what you are looking for since the div is moving from bottom to top but the idea is the same.
Create three divs: *main-container*, *alert-container*, *alert-content*

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="alert-container">
  <!-- placeholder image -->
  <img class="inner_img" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" />
    <div class="alert-content">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
         <strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then apply this css

```
.main-container{
 position: relative; /* Set to absolute */
}
.alert-container {
 position: absolute; /* Set to absolute and positioned at top corner*/
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.alert-content {
 position: absolute;   /* This moves it to the bottom (initial state) */
 bottom: 90%; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 transition: bottom 1s;
}
.main-container:hover .alert-content {
  bottom: 50%;   /* This moves it to the middle (only on hover) */
}
```

i have made a fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/akassama/8scets7b/) with bootstrap alerts and made the transition from top to the middle of the page. You can adjust it accordingly.